# Installing services as different users

Tags: windows, service, filebeat

I was installing the filebeat application and I noticed that I needed to run powershell as administrator in order to install them. When I checked the service using `wmic service get name,startname,status` it showed Local System. I'm wondering what this account is as this is neither the user account or the administrator account. Will this always be the case when I install services as administrator? What is the difference if I install it as a normal user and as administrator?

In any case, I've set this service to start automatically when windows start. Would this service start only when the user I used to install it logs in or will it start regardless of which user logs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's unpack that one by one, in no particular order:

- Only a user with administrator rights can install a service.
- Services that are configured to start automatically are started as soon as Windows is up and running; Windows does not wait until somebody logs in.  It makes no difference to the service who the logged-on user is, or whether anybody is logged in at all, unless the service application itself has been explicitly programmed to check.
- The program that installs the service decides what account the service uses to run.  Windows doesn't care what user account was used to install the service, it doesn't even keep track.
- If the program that installs the service wants it to use an ordinary user account, it must know the password for that account.  There are various special accounts that a service can run in, these accounts do not require a password.  One of these special accounts is Local System.
- Local System is the highest-privilege service account in Windows; it has all the same rights as an administrator, *and* can do things an administrator can't.  Local System is also the account that the user-mode part of Windows itself runs in, *roughly* equivalent to the UNIX root account except that it doesn't have a password.

Additional notes, for completeness:

- One alternative to Local System is for the service to run as Local Service or as Network Service, which are non-administrative service accounts.  The only difference between the two is that if the computer is joined to an Active Directory domain, the Network Service account has network access to other machines in the domain and the Local Service account does not.
- It is also possible to configure a service to run in a special service account that is unique to that particular service.  This is mostly useful if you want the service to have access to a particular file or folder, but do not want to give it administrator rights.

Nitpickers corner:

- It is I believe technically possible to reconfigure Windows to allow non-administrators to install services, but this is not supported and would be a Very Bad Idea.  If you did, though, it would still make no difference who installed the service.  Windows doesn't record this information.

Comment: I see. thanks. For filebeats' case, if you're familiar with it, is it the same as the usual service? which starts as soon as windows start?

Comment: I've never heard of it.  But if that's how the service is configured, that's what Windows will do.

Comment: Thanks for your response.